# wrong buffer value retrieved from mql5 indicator using iCustom

Tags: mql4, mql5, mql, metatrader5

I just moved from mql4 to mql5  and now i am trying to read  buffers values from an indicator , but it only shows me 0 instead of the actual buffer values

[image]

**Here is my code :**

```
#property version   "1.00"

int handle1 = 0;

double valu1,valu2,valu3,valu4;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//--- create timer
   EventSetTimer(60);
   handle1 = iCustom(NULL, NULL, "LTD by KDMfx");
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//--- destroy timer
   EventKillTimer();
   IndicatorRelease(handle1);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Get indicator value                                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double GetIndicator(int handle, int buffer_num, int index)
  {
 
   double arr[];
 
   if(CopyBuffer(handle, buffer_num, 0, index+1, arr) <= 0)
     {
      Sleep(200);
      for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
         if(BarsCalculated(handle) > 0)
            break;
         Sleep(50);
        }
      int copied = CopyBuffer(handle, buffer_num, 0, index+1, arr);
      if(copied <= 0)
        {
         Print("CopyBuffer failed. Maybe history has not download yet? Error = ", GetLastError());
         return -1;
        }
      else
         return (arr[index]);
     }


   return 0;
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
//---
   valu1 = GetIndicator(handle1,0,4);
   valu2 = GetIndicator(handle1,1,4);
   valu3 = GetIndicator(handle1,2,4);
   valu4 = GetIndicator(handle1,3,4);
   
   Comment("b1: ", valu1,
            "\nb2: ", valu2,
               "\nb3: ", valu3,
                  "\nb4: ", valu4 
            
            );
  }
```

**what am i doing wrong here ?**
the indicator does not appear on the current or the last closed candle , it appears on the current+4 candle , meaning on the 5th candle in past . so i am using "4" as the candle id but still no use , no matter what i try i can get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simplifying things a bit. I don't have a copy of the indicator you are trying to read, but the following code should work

```
#property version       "1.10"
#property strict

int handle;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Initialization function of the expert                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
   handle=iCustom(_Symbol, 0, "LTD by KDMfx");
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Deinitialization function of the expert                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
   IndicatorRelease(handle);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Tick" event handler function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
   double LTDindicator[];
   ArraySetAsSeries(LTDindicator, true);
   CopyBuffer(handle, 0, 0, 25, LTDindicator);

   Comment(LTDindicator[0]);

return;
}
```